# SSH with a bastion host and different usernames

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tunneling, ssh-config

I want to log into a linux server using two sequential bastion hosts.
My `.ssh/config` file looks something like this:

```
Host *
  User username0
Host hostname0
  Hostname foo
Host hostname1
  Hostname bar
  Port 0
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hostname0
Host hostname2
  User username2
  Hostname bat
  Port 1
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hostname1
```

My username on `hostname0` and `hostname1` is `username0` but my username on `hostname2` is `username2`.

The entries for hostname0 and hostname1 work as expected. But the entry for `hostname2` appears to ignore the `User` option.

`ssh hostname2` causes this to be displayed:

```
username0@hostname2's password:
```

If I change the ProxyCommand for hostname2 to `ssh -l username2 -W %h:%p hostname1` then it asks me for the password for username2@hostname1.
`username2@hostname1's password`  which makes sense as I am asking it to log into `hostname1` as `username2`, but it obviously doesn't work as my username is actually `username0`.

How can I configure ssh to use the correct username in each situation?

Comment: Why two bastion hosts? I would use a VPN plus a jumpbox.

Comment: @ruiFRibeiro It wasn't my choice.  I am connecting to a different company's network through another organization that is semi-separate from both.  There is actually a VPN in the mix too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different order of the `Host` blocks. The `Host *` matches everything and `ssh_config` does not overwrite already stored entries:

```
Host hostname0
  Hostname foo
Host hostname1
  Hostname bar
  Port 0
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hostname0
Host hostname2
  User username2
  Hostname bat
  Port 1
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hostname1
Host *
  User username0
```

Moving the `Host *` to the end will make it working for you again.

Comment: That did it.  I assumed that the more-specific entry would win, but that is clearly not the case. Thanks!

Comment: No. It is explained in the above mentioned manual page: *"For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used"*